# How to avoid screening quotes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I want to store some data in my DB and it can be with quotation marks:

```
$data = 'some "quoted" text';    
$id = DB::table('some_table')->insertGetId(array('data' => $data);
```

So I obviously get screened quotes in my DB field:

```
some \"quoted\" text
```

I tried to avoid it according to Laravel 4 docs:

```
$id = DB::table('some_table')->insertGetId(array('data' => DB::raw($data));
```

But it rises syntax error `SQLSTATE[42000]`.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to insert raw data into your database? Can't you use `stripslashes` when displaying it?

Comment: erm.... laravel doesn't do that i suppose?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks for solving my problem, Alessandro. It works for me this way too!

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc is on?  There is no reason you would need to run stripslashes on a string you got back out of the database, unless extra slashes are being introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "avoid" escaping of string literals.

A mysql string literal is denoted by single or double quotes.  So there is no way that you can have a string which INCLUDES those characters INSIDE of it, without mysql having the escape character.  There is a varbinary type, but I don't think that's what you should be looking at.  With that said, if you send in an escape character you won't see that in the table.  If you're looking at the table from the mysql command line and seeing escapes in the field, there is some sort of escape duplication happening.

Furthermore, omitting the escaping process is the primary introduction point for SQL injections -- namely, confusing the SQL statement parser by introducing text and extraneous quotes that get parsed as SQL.

Laravel's query builder is intentionally hiding all these details from you, and that's the way it should be.

There is however, one thing you should look into -- and that's the setting of magic_quotes_gpc.  You should insure that this is NOT enabled, as it automatically runs addslashes on all input, and can result in double quotes.

I'm not clear from the way your question was posed, exactly what the problem is.  Laravel should be taking care of all these details for you transparently (escaping/unescaping).  What is broken, that you are trying to fix?